# Should we change the policy on downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, reputation

I think that the policy of the user losing reputation for casting is counterproductive as it disenfranchises users from giving honest opinion & expressing dissent. Shouldn't there be any change in this policy ?

Comment: Do you mean the OP losing its reputation for downvotes to its content? That's necessary, as it is expected to have good quality research and presentation for both Q/A. otherwise, we'll have a sheer increase in the volume of content generated and a degradation in quality. Downvotes are a reminder that there is further refining and proper writing of the answer. More reputation would then properly co-relate to both quality and quantity.

Comment: Related: [Why do you lose reputation for downvoting answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/260388)